# Get cart total including last added item in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I'm trying to get the cart total when hooking into `woocommerce_add_to_cart`. That works, but the cart total returned is the total prior to the last added item. I want the updated total, to be able to display a notice regarding shipping costs.

Any idea how to achieve this?

My current code:

```
function oppsalg_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Limit
    $minimum_cart_total = 1000;

    // Cart value (Not including the last added item)
    $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Comparison
    if( $total < $minimum_cart_total ) {
        // Display notice
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>Shipping is free above %s.</strong>'
            .'<br />Your total is %s. Perhaps you would like to add more items?',
            $minimum_cart_total,
            $total ),
        'notice' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'oppsalg_add_to_cart');
```

Comment: Are you able to use AJAX add to cart functionality instead of the standard POST way?  If so then you can modify the add to cart message with some filters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure AJAX is what is already being used. What filter(s) should I be looking into?

Comment: The filter 'wc_add_to_cart_message' or 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html' will fire when you add products to your cart via AJAX.  You can use this to change the message users see.  However it seems like it only calls the wc_add_to_cart_message() function if the option 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' is set to yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, just tested this solution on adding a single page product to the cart without AJAX.  This won't modify the message you see when you change the cart quantity on the Cart page though via AJAX.  Also you should make the shipping cost dynamic so that it's not hard coded like I have done below, that can be your homework to fix.

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'modify_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );

function modify_wc_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) {

    $minimum_cart_total = 100;
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    if( $cart_total < $minimum_cart_total ) {
        $message = sprintf( '<strong>Shipping is free above %s.</strong>'
                            .'<br />Your total is %s. Perhaps you would like to add more items?',
                            wc_price( $minimum_cart_total ),
                            wc_price( $cart_total )
                            );
    }

    return $message;
}
```